# Elimiate CSS render-blocking, best way

Tags: css, render-blocking

i want to eliminate the render blocking from my website, but i can't. 
I don't use external css files, or fonts, only just a big css file.
When i copyall content from css file in head AllcontentCSS, render blocking disappear from Google Page Insights
Is there a way to eliminate render blocking and include the css file with link in head instead to copy all css in style tag or is good to insert the css in body tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely looking for:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourFile.css" media="none" onload="if(media!='all')media='all'">
```

But, before you proceed, please read the following resources detailing the technique and its limitations:

- [initial article](https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/loading-css-without-blocking-render/) by Keith Clark
- [follow up](https://codepen.io/tigt/post/async-css-without-javascript) by Taylor Hunt.

Make sure you also go through the links provided by Taylor Hunt. You probably want to use [loadCSS](https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS) function/polyfill from Filament Group.

But be aware this technique will cause FOUC on your page. You should divide your CSS into two parts:

- layout basics (load normally - render blocking),
- async styles (load async).